# I have a problem with Laravel, when i try to logout users I get Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pullCache does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Help... I Recently upgraded Laravel from 5.5 to >> 5.6 and now when I logout I get...

Arguments

> > Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pullCache does not exist.

```php
    /**
     * Handle dynamic method calls into the method.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($method, 'where')) {
            return $this->dynamicWhere($method, $parameters);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
            'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` after updating should refresh your autoloads.

Comment: Thanks @Script47,   Just did and the error is still showing

Comment: Try: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: No, still showing does it have anything to do with the logout functions that ship with laravel?

Comment: Does the file exist? Try: `composer update` then the first command I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 5.6 Use logout like this

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
onclick="event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
<i class="demo-pli-unlock icon-lg icon-fw"></i>
Logout
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you i see no difference with what i previously had,
 `<a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
           onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
           {{ __('Logout') }}
        </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>`